# How com I can log in to firebase with fake Password?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

However, if I refresh the page after disconnecting and reconnect afterwards with a fake mass password, then firebase send an error message and I cannot be connected.
In my App component, here is wnere I manage the onAuthStateChanged  :

```
const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true))
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user){
            dispatch(setCurrentUser({email: user.email}))
            console.log("user connecté :", user.email)
            setNewUser(user)
        }else {
            dispatch(setCurrentUser(false));
            console.log("user deconnecté !!")
            setNewUser(null)
    }
    dispatch(setLoading(false))
    })
    return () => unsubscribe()
}, [dispatch])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("État de l'utilisateur mis à jour:", newUser);
}, [newUser]);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(totalPrice())
}, [cartItems])
```

Here, "user email" return user's email as well, same for "user deconnected" when LogOut.
In the second useEffect, I retrieve all user's info.
Thank you in advance.

I try to sign in to my account with a fake password and I expect to be rejected with an error message.
This is the case if Irefresh the page.
Otherwise, if I reconnect without refreshing, I will be connected without receiving any error message

Comment: Please edit your sign in and sign out code into your question. The code shown above is only showing your authentication state listener and not how you are modifying it.